# add rows and columns base on condition in laravel blade

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create UI for cinema seats in laravel blade. i have seat_rows and seat_coulmns in my database and seat_rows will be the same for 2 rows. i mean first row is like this: id:1 seat_row:1 seat_column:1 and second row is like this: id:2 seat_row:1 seat:column:2. so i using bootstrap row and col classes and i wanna add row class only when number of seat_row changes. how can I DO that?

@foreach ($allseats as $seat)

```
{{-- @while ($seat->seat_row !== $seat->seat_row) --}}
   <div id="{{$seat->seat_row}}" class="row "> 

       {{-- @for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) --}}
          <div id="{{$seat->id}}" class="col-2 seats ">
            <img  src="{{asset('assets/img/seats/seat1.png')}}" alt="" style="height:50px;width:50px">
            </div>  
       {{-- @endfor --}}


    </div>  

{{-- @endwhile --}}
    {{$newrow=$seat->seat_row}}
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to compare it with the previous seat.
Instead of using `@foreach ($allseats as $seat)` you can use `@foreach ($allseats as $key => $seat)`

and then check in your loop if `$seat !== $allseats[$key-1]`

I hope that guides you on the correct track.

Comment: thank you so much for your respond but when i tried your suggestion i get undefined offset error but i solved my problem with defining a variable before foreach loop and again inside it like this and it solve my problem:{{$newrow=null}}

 foreach ($allseats as  $seat)  

    if ( $seat->seat_row !== $newrow )
{{$newrow=$seat->seat_row}}
    endif
 endforeach

Comment: Good to hear, if you believe my solution could profit others, please mark it as approved 